# How to Transform [Object Object] to Array objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to loop over each object within the object and recreate an array of object as shown below

First object

```
Object {
  "65657-33E-2442": Object {
    "description": "description qwerty",
    "imageUrl": "wwxxxxzdce.jpg",
    "time": "11/11/11 09:00",
    "title": "title",
  },
  "762873-773-33838": Object {
    "description": "2description qwerty2",
    "imageUrl": "2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2",
    "time": "22/22/22 09:00",
    "title": "2title2",
  },
}
```

I want to get a result like this :

```
[
      {
         "description": "description qwerty",
         "imageUrl": "wwxxxxzdce.jpg",
         "time": "11/11/11 09:00",
         "title": "title",
      },
      {
         "description": "2description qwerty2",
         "imageUrl": "2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2",
         "time": "22/22/22 09:00",
         "title": "2title2",
      },
]
```

#2 : this is the array that the object.values ​​function gives me

```
Array [
  ChildrenNode {
    "children_": SortedMap {
      "comparator_": [Function NAME_COMPARATOR],
      "root_": LLRBNode {
        "color": false,
.......
.......
```

My function

```
  const getAgenda = async () => {
    await getEvents().then((res) => {
      console.log(res) //this return first object
      console.log(Object.values(res)) //this return #2
    })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `Object.entries()` or `Object.values()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this not reslove my problem

Answer (score -1):

Use `Object.values`:

```
Object.values({
    "65657-33E-2442": {
        "description": "description qwerty",
        "imageUrl": "wwxxxxzdce.jpg",
        "time": "11/11/11 09:00",
        "title": "title",
    },
    "762873-773-33838": {
        "description": "2description qwerty2",
        "imageUrl": "2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2",
        "time": "22/22/22 09:00",
        "title": "2title2",
    },
})
```

Will return:

```
[
  {
    description: 'description qwerty',
    imageUrl: 'wwxxxxzdce.jpg',
    time: '11/11/11 09:00',
    title: 'title'
  },
  {
    description: '2description qwerty2',
    imageUrl: '2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2',
    time: '22/22/22 09:00',
    title: '2title2'
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, 
it return me this
Array [
  ChildrenNode {
    "children_": SortedMap {...............

Comment: I answered the original question, is this another question ? If so, you can open another question on Stack Overflow and accept this answer

Comment: No it's the same question the console log gives me this result

Comment: Array [
  "k",
  "o",
]

Answer (score -1):

For a more complete example:

```js
const input = {
  "65657-33E-2442": {
    "description": "description qwerty",
    "imageUrl": "wwxxxxzdce.jpg",
    "time": "11/11/11 09:00",
    "title": "title",
  },
  "762873-773-33838": {
    "description": "2description qwerty2",
    "imageUrl": "2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2",
    "time": "22/22/22 09:00",
    "title": "2title2",
  },
}

console.log(Object.values(input))

/*
This will print:
[
      {
         "description": "description qwerty",
         "imageUrl": "wwxxxxzdce.jpg",
         "time": "11/11/11 09:00",
         "title": "title",
      },
      {
         "description": "2description qwerty2",
         "imageUrl": "2wwxxxxzdce.jpg2",
         "time": "22/22/22 09:00",
         "title": "2title2",
      },
]
*/
```